# Save Snowpark DataFrame as text file in Snowflake Stage

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

My requirement is to take tabular data in Snowflake and save it as a csv file to Snowflake External Stage, where data has header and footer.

Is this doable using Snowpark(Python)?
Result should look something like below where col1, col2, col3 are columns in Snowflake table

```
        Australia Sales as at 2023-8-31. Version is 2021.01
        Output_Format, CSV
        NUMLINES,      6781
        ---------------------------------
        col1, col2, col3
        xxx,yyy,zzz
        .....
        xxx,yyy,zzz
        ---------------------------------
        ##END##
        ##COLOR####ENDCOLOR##
        ##FORMULA####ENDFORMULA##
```

Comment: If by header/footer you mean the text before/after the dotted lines, how are you planning to save this to a csv file when the data is not in a csv format?

Comment: by csv I rather meant file extension (*.csv) than pure csv format. Essentially, it's text file where the data part of it is csv.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with Snowpark Python API `DataFrameWriter.copy_into_location` as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrameWriter.copy_into_location)

Here is an example:

```
df = session.create_dataframe(
            [["John", "Berry"], ["Rick", "Berry"], ["Anthony", "Davis"]],
            schema=["FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME"],
        )
df.write.copy_into_location(
            ext_stage,
            partition_by=partition_by,
            file_format_type="csv",
            format_type_options={"COMPRESSION": "GZIP"},
            header=True,
            overwrite=False,
        )
```

Comment: this obviously won't work, because of the header and footer required in the same file.

Comment: If the header/footer are mandatory then it's not possible as of now with currently available APIs.

Comment: can I access stage with standard python `open` ?
e.g. 
``` with open("@stage_name/dir/file.csv","w") as f: 
            f.write(variable_with_text) ```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I believe it's not possible to do that on external stages.